# css error stopping deployment

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

In the process of deploying a Rails application to a VPS, and I'm running into a few CSS errors that are causing the rake tasks to be aborted. I don't think the CSS error below is one that I created but is rather arising from the joining of files, and I'm having a hard time debugging it.  I have two css files in my app (one being the application.css) , neither of which is 1342 lines long (which is what I'm assuming the 1342 below refers to). Both of the CSS files end with this

```
*/*/*/
```

which is related to the error

```
Invalid CSS after "*/*/*/": expected "{", was ""
 ** [out :: 198.XXX] 
 ** [out :: 198.XXX] (in /home/brain/apps/dogapp/releases/20130628194843/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
 ** [out :: 198.XXX] 
 ** [out :: 198.XXX] (sass):1342
```

My application.css file acts as the manifest file but it also has a lot of css code in it, and the other css file just has css in it.

Note, I'm not running `rake assets:precompile` on my local machine if that's important, as it seems to be triggered by the deployment script I'm borrowing from R Bates.

Can you explain this error?

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require bootstrap.min
 *= require_tree .
 */

body {
  padding-top: 60px; 
  font-family: Helvetica Neue,Arial,sans-serif;
}
ul {

  list-style-type: none;
}
#ommitted code


   aside {
  textarea {
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
}
*/*/*/
```

Comment: Not sure if it's related, but I am pretty sure there should be quotes around "Helvetica Neue".

Comment: around all of them, or just that one because it's two words?

Comment: Just that one considering it's two words.

Comment: good to know but after fixing that I'm getting the same error deploying, so I don't think it's related

Comment: Where is the `*/*/*/` coming from?  It isn't valid in CSS or Sass.

Comment: @cinnamon I have no idea. I had never thought about it. I just removed it (to test) and the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

I removed `*/*/*/` from the bottom of both files and the problem went away. I have no idea where it came from, I assume Rails put it there for some reason.